# Регулярка на PHP - разрешить кавычки

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Фильтрую пользовательские данные для заголовка (буквы, цифры, пробел, тире и подчёркивание):

```
preg_match('/^[\da-zа-яё\,\-\_ ]{'.$min.','.$max.'}$/iu',$sValue
```

**Вопрос** - как разрешить кавычки-лапки (")?  Добавление в набор символов почему-то не работает..

```
[\da-zа-яё\,\-\_" ]
```

Comment: а `$sValue` откуда берете и чем обрабатываете?

Comment: $sValue приходит из разных мест, в основном $_POST $_GET 

Кстати да - скорее всего нужно слэши убить. Спасибо за наводку!

Comment: и если там прошло htmlspecialchars - поюзать `htmlentities_decode()`

Comment: ок, в данном случае ограничился stripslashes(), но в для прочих случаев буду помнить.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^[0-9a-zа-яё,_"-]{0, 5}$/iu
```

«**-**» — указывайте всегда последним, так как этот символ указывает на диапазон.

**`a-z-_`** — не правильно!